# how to solve an equation in scala using actors?

Tags: scala, actor, message-passing

I want to know how an actor returns a value to the sender and how to store it in a variable.

For example, consider that we have to find the sum of squares of 2 numbers and print it.

i.e., sum = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>

I have 2 actors. 1 actor computes square of any number passed to it (say, `SquareActor`). The other actor sends the two numbers (a , b) to the `SquareActor` and computes their sum (say, `SumActor`)

```
/** Actor to find the square of a number */

class SquareActor (x: Int) extends Actor
{
  def act()
  {
    react{
        case x : Int => println (x * x)  
        // how to return the value of x*x to "SumActor" ?
    }
  } 
}

/** Actor to find the sum of squares of a and b */

class SumActor (a: Int, b:Int) extends Actor
{
  def act()
  {
    var a2 = 0
    var b2 = 0        

    val squareActor = new SquareActor (a : Int)   
    squareActor.start

    // call squareActor to get a*a 
    squareActor ! a 
// How to get the value returned by SquareActor and store it in the variable 'a2' ?

    // call squareActor to get b*b 
    squareActor ! b
// How to get the value returned by SquareActor and store it in the variable 'b2' ?

    println ("Sum: " + a2+b2)
  } 
}
```

Pardon me if the above is not possible; I think my basic understanding of actors may itself be wrong.

Comment: I'm very interested in symbolic mathematics, and this code looks very elegant and concise for an equation solver, but I fail to see *how* it solves equations? It looks to me like it simply computes a basic function?

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Akka

Note that from Scala 2.10, the [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) actor library is an integrated part of the standard library. It is generally considered superior to the standard actor library, so getting familiar with that would benefit you.

#### Use Futures

Also note that what you want to achieve is easier and nicer (composes better) using [Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html). A `Future[A]` represents a possibly concurrent computation, eventually yielding a result of type `A`.

```
def asyncSquare(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future(x * x)
val sq1 = asyncSquare(2)
val sq2 = asyncSquare(3)

val asyncSum = 
  for {
    a <- sq1
    b <- sq2
  }
  yield (a + b)
```

Note that the `asyncSquare` results are queried in advance to start their (independent) computations as soon as possible. Putting the calls inside the `for` comprehension would have serialized their execution, not using the possible concurrency.

You use `Future`-s in `for` comprehensions, `map`, `flatMap`, `zip`, `sequence` them, and in the very end, you can get the computed value using `Await`, which is a blocking operation, or using registered callbacks.

#### Use Futures with actors

It is handy that you can `ask` from actors, which results in a `Future`:

```
val futureResult: Future[Int] = (someActor ? 5).mapTo[Int]
```

Note the need to use of `mapTo` because the message passing interface of actors is not typed (there are however [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/java/typed-actors.html)).

#### Bottom line

If you want to perform stateless computations in parallel, stick to plain `Future`s. If you need stateful but local computations, you can still use `Future` and thread the state yourself (or use scalaz StateT monad transformer + Future as monad, if you are on to that business). If you need computations which require global state, then isolate that state into an actor, and interact with that actor, possibly using `Future`s.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that actors work by *message passing*. So to get the response from the `SquareActor` back to the `SumActor`, you need to send it as a message from the `SquareActor`, and add a handler to the `SumActor`.

Also, your `SquareActor` constructor doesn't need an integer parameter.

That is, in your `SquareActor`, instead of just printing `x * x`, pass it to the `SumActor`:

```
class SquareActor extends Actor
{
  def act()
  {
    react{
        case x : Int => sender ! (x * x)  
    }
  } 
}
```

(`sender` causes it to send the message to the actor that sent the message it is reacting to.)

In your `SumActor`, after you send `a` and `b` to the `SquareActor`, handle the received reply messages:

```
react {
  case a2 : Int => react {
    case b2 : Int => println ("Sum: " + (a2+b2))
  }
}
```